# Windows 7 screen position too low on startup

Tags: windows-7, display

Over the last several weeks, when I start up my Acer Netbook with Windows 7 starter, the first screen with the enter password box is loading up about an inch too low. As a result every screen winds up being too low ant the bottom of every page gets cut off and I can't scroll all the way down.

At first I would get this problem every once in a while, now it is happening constantly. Once in a while it will start up in the right location

The people at Microsoft says it is a problem with the operating system and offered to fix it at a substantial cost since the warranty just expired, of course. I also chatted with the manufacturer who suggested the problem was (a) corrupt file(s). I listened to their suggested solution and formatted the hard drive back to factory default condition. for a minute it looked like I solved the problem as on the first couple of start ups the problem was gone. But soon after attempting to restore my files the problem came back and I still have it.

I would appreciate any suggestions you may have, as this problem with the cut off screen is affecting my ability to work.

Comment: Do you have the latest graphics drivers installed from Acer? Can you boot into safe mode and see if the issue persists with the base VGA driver?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a multi-step problem.

First way of fixing it:

1. Reformat the hard drive again (a pain, I know).
2. Reload every piece of software/data on one piece at a time.
3. Repeat step 2 until you notice the screen issue.
4. Logic would lead one to believe that the previous piece of data is where the issue is arising from.

Second idea I had:

Maybe it's an issue with your display/monitor.  I know you're on a laptop, so I don't know any way to figure this out, but on stand-alone's they have the "Auto Focus" which helps when the graphics get moved off screen.